# Что такое "верес"?

Tags: значение-слов

У нас есть фирма, выпускающая овощные консервы и соусы - "Верес" (кстати, очень неплохая). Но вот интересно, а что означает это слово - "верес"? И от него идет, видимо, славянское название сентября - "вересень".
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верес (по Далю -вереск душистый, ягодный, восковой, пахучка, восковник, восковница, болотная мирта) — можжевельник, род вечнозелёных хвойных кустарников и деревьев семейства Кипарисовые.     http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/838133

Его считают магическим растением и используют в  религиозных обрядах: Верес - можжевельник, собираемый в Чистый четверг Страстной недели Великого поста. Атрибут предпасхальных очистительных и защитных обрядов.

http://www.ethnomuseum.ru/section62/2092/2089/4091.htm